# Find the value of the expectation $E(X)$ of the following distribution.

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a random variable having the distribution function 
>   $$F(x)=\begin{cases}
> 0 &\text{if } x<0\\
> \frac{1}{4} & \text{if } 0\leq x<1\\
> \frac{1}{3} & \text{if } 1\leq x<2\\
> \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } 2\leq x<11/3\\
> 1& \text{if } x\geq 11/3\end{cases}$$
>
> Find the value of $E(X)$.

Now we know $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{4}xdx+\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{3}xdx+\int_{2}^{11/3}\frac{1}{2}xdx$,

now I am stuck as i don't know what to do with $x\geq 11/3$? Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: The formula you "know" applies to random variables with a density, that is, that are *continuous*. Do you think this $X$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes I have copied it correctly. The given answer is $2.25$

Comment: I don't know, it seems it's a cumulative distribution @Did

Comment: Not my question. Of course F is a CDF, the question is what is the kind of distribution it is a CDF of.

Comment: Ok it is a CDF of a discrete random variable. @Did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing isn't a continuous random variable, so the formula you're using doesn't work.

I recommend drawing this thing out.

The expectation is
$$E[X] = (1-0)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)+(2-1)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right) +\left(\frac{11}{3}-2\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)=2.25$$

---

Alternatively, the distribution of $X$ is
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & \frac{11}{3}\\\hline
P(X = x)& \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
Then,
$$E[X] = 0(1/4)+1(1/12)+2(1/6)+(11/3)(1/2) = 2.25$$

Comment: Which formula you'd use?

Comment: @user290591 I guess it's a tail sum. Try drawing the discrete pmf and calculating it that way. The answers should match.

Comment: Ok will try....

Comment: @user290591 Ok, you can check your work against mine. Also, in your original post, it should be "$1$ if $x\leq \frac{11}{3}$".